# PL/pgSQL function to INSERT array of rows

Tags: arrays, postgresql, plpgsql

I want to have a function written in PL/pgSQL that takes as parameter something like "collection of row", I mean I need to pass a dictionary-like structure to the function.

Pseudocode:

```
function_name({key1:val1,key2:val2, key3:val3 [, ...] })
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 11):

With modern day PostgreSQL you can simplify such a function.
Test setup:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl1 (id int, value text);
```

No need to create a type explicitly in this case (if the type is based on a table row), it is created for every table implicitly.
Function:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION f_insert_rows_into_tbl1(tbl1[])
  RETURNS void
  LANGUAGE sql AS
$func$
INSERT INTO tbl1  -- rare case where it's safe to omit target columns
SELECT *
FROM   unnest($1) sub;
$func$;
```

Since the composite row type is the only column in the subquery, it will be decomposed in the outer `SELECT` automatically.

Since the input type is defined by the table row, this is one of the rare cases where it's safe to omit target columns for the `INSERT` command. In fact, it may even be advisable - to stay in sync with possible future changes to the table definition.

Call:

```
SELECT f_insert_rows_into_tbl1('{"(1,foo)","(2,bar)"}');
```

Note the input syntax for an array of rows! If you are uncertain about the correct syntax, see:

- [Correct syntax for array of composite type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35955943/correct-syntax-for-array-of-composite-type/35979476#35979476)

Answer (score 1):

Visit this site http://postgres.cz/wiki/PostgreSQL_SQL_Tricks and search for Array to table. There may be other ways on newer versions, but I had this in my bookmarks from awhile back.
Source from website:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION unpack(anyarray)
RETURNS SETOF anyelement AS $$ 
SELECT $1[i] 
   FROM generate_series(array_lower($1,1), 
                        array_upper($1,1)) g(i);
$$ LANGUAGE sql STRICT IMMUTABLE;

select unpack(array['a','b','c']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a composite type and array argument. Something like (untested):

```
create type keyvalue as (
  key text,
  value text
);

create function function_name(keyvalue[]) returns null as $$
declare
  keyvalue x;
begin
  foreach x in array $1 loop
    insert into tablename(key,value) values (x.key, x.value);
  end loop
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

This will not be a true dictionary, as you can add duplicate `keyvalue`s and `keyvalue`s with the same key and different value to this array. But just for passing arguments to a function it should be enough.

Using `unpack()` mentioned by [JustBob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/102388/justbob) will allow to not use a loop, which is not very SQL-y, but treat this array as a set.

Comment: Untested solutions aren't helpful. Please try to test before posting.