# Correct syntax for array of composite type

Tags: arrays, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

```
CREATE TYPE pencil_count AS(
    pencil_color varchar(30),
    count integer
);

CREATE TABLE pencils(id serial, pencils_ pencil_count[]);

INSERT INTO pencils(pencils_) VALUES('{("blue",5),("red",2)}');
```

This doesn't work and gives error:

> Malformed array literal.

What would be the correct syntax if I want to add this composite array without using **`ARRAY[...]`**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *I want to add this composite array without using **ARRAY***

You could use:

```
INSERT INTO pencils(pencils_) 
VALUES('{"(\"blue\",5)","(\"red\",2)"}');
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=da7cad5d6576a92cdbb00b69da5ed09d)**

> [Row type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rowtypes.html)
>
> **Remember that what you write in an SQL command will first be interpreted as a string literal, and then as a composite. This doubles the number of backslashes you need (assuming escape string syntax is used).**
>
> The string-literal processor removes one level of backslashes.
>
> The ROW constructor syntax is usually easier to work with than the composite-literal syntax when writing composite values in SQL commands. In ROW, individual field values are written the same way they would be written when not members of a composite.

Comment: I need to pass func params through a driver, so I have to use a literal for an array of composite types.  Couldn't figure out how to format text with a comma and was shooting in the dark for Hours.  Finally found this post! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 13):

Advice so far is not optimal. There is a simpler solution and actually applicable explanation.
When in doubt, **just ask Postgres to show you**:

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE pencil_count (  -- table also registers row type
  pencil_color varchar(30)
, count integer
);

CREATE TEMP TABLE pencils (
  id serial
, pencils_ pencil_count[]
);
```

Insert 2 basic rows:

```
INSERT INTO pencil_count VALUES ('red', 1), ('blue', 2);
```

See the syntax for the *basic row type*:

```
SELECT p::text AS p_row FROM pencil_count p;

  p_row
----------
 (red,1)
 (blue,2)
```

See the syntax for an *array of rows*:

```
SELECT ARRAY(SELECT p FROM pencil_count p)::text AS p_row_arr;

       p_row_arr
------------------------
 {"(red,1)","(blue,2)"}
```

All you need is to enclose each row literal in double quotes - which is only necessary to disable the special meaning of the *comma* within each row type.
Additional (escaped) double quotes would be redundant noise while there are no additional special characters.

None of this has anything to do with <strike>escape string syntax</strike>, which has been turned *off* by default since Postgres 9.1. You would have to declare escape string syntax explicitly by prefixing `E`, like `E'string\n'`. But there is no good reason to do that.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0l3bfNLN)
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/32363/1)</sub>

Related answer with more explanation:

- [Insert text with single quotes in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-varchar-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql/12320729#12320729)
- [How to pass custom type array to Postgres function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009822/how-to-pass-custom-type-array-to-postgres-function/17840058#17840058)
- [PL/pgSQL function to INSERT array of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9640087/pl-pgsql-array-of-rows/9642082#9642082)

Comment: I appreciate for the answer..!