# How to add array of table data type to function as IN parameter?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, plpgsql

I want to add more than one row into table using function,
but unable to pass F1(`thebook book[]`) as.
Kindly assist if any solution.

---

```
CREATE TABLE book
(
  id smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,       
  bname text,       
  btype text,
  bprices numeric(11,2)[],
  CONSTRAINT key PRIMARY KEY (id )
);
```

---

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION save_book(thebook book)
  RETURNS text AS
  $BODY$
DECLARE 
  myoutput text :='Nothing has occured';
BEGIN

  update book set 
  bname=thebook.bname,
  btype=thebook.btype,bprices=thebook.bprices  WHERE id=thebook.id;

  IF FOUND THEN
    myoutput:= 'Record with PK[' || thebook.id || '] successfully updated';
    RETURN myoutput;
  END IF;

  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO book values(thebook.id,thebook.bname,thebook.btype, thebook.bprices);
    myoutput:= 'Record successfully added';           
  END;
  RETURN myoutput;

END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

---

```
SELECT save_book(row(111,'the art of living','ABC', array[190,220])::book);
```

Comment: So do you have your answer?

Answer (score 0):

- For up to 100 rows, use a `VARIADIC` parameter for convenience. This way you can list individual rows and don't have figure out the complex syntax for an *array of rows*. The parameter is still visible as array inside the function. Details:

  - [Return rows matching elements of input array in plpgsql function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978310/select-rows-such-that-names-match-elements-of-input-array-for-pgsql-function/17978831#17978831)
  - [PL/pgSQL Array of Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9640087/pl-pgsql-array-of-rows/9642082#9642082)
- Use the new UPSERT implementation in Postgres **9.5+** `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT UPDATE`:
- Unnest the array with `unnest()`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION save_book(VARIADIC thebook book[])
  RETURNS void AS
$func$
BEGIN

INSERT INTO book(id, bname, btype, bprices)  -- spell out target columns!
SELECT *
FROM   unnest(thebook) t
ON     CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE
SET    bname = excluded.bname                -- excluded key word!
     , btype = excluded.btype
     , bprices = excluded.bprices;

END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT save_book('(111,"the art of living",ABCX, "{190,220}")'
               , '(112,"the art of living",ABCY, "{190,220}")');
```

Related:

- [How to include excluded rows in RETURNING from INSERT ... ON CONFLICT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35949877/how-to-include-excluded-rows-in-returning-from-insert-on-conflict/35953488#35953488)
- [Is SELECT or INSERT in a function prone to race conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939902/is-select-or-insert-in-a-function-prone-to-race-conditions/15950324#15950324)